# Magento 2 cart getItemsCount always return 0

Tags: caching, shopping-cart, cart, magento2

I am new in Magento 2 and I feel a bit pain on the cart items count, I created in custom module but I noticed that when FPC cache is enabled in the admin it always return 0 on some other pages.

on my block:

```
public function getItemsCount(){

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of Object Manager
        $cartHelper = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart');
        return $cartHelper->getItemsCount();

    }
```

On my template:

```
echo $block->getItemsCount() ;
```

I tried to use cacheable="false" and _isScopePrivate="true" but nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: Which Magento 2 version you are using? Magento 2 have lot of bugs (some of them are related with cache management)

Comment: Im using Magento 2.1.